# Converting File Path From NSString To NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working through Cocoa smoothly, but this problem seems so basic it cancels out all the cool stuff I learned. :/

I have a generated file path, and it needs to be in NSURL format. From research, this is the code I wrote:

```
NSLog(@"Old path = %@", pathToFile);
NSURL *xmlURL = [[[NSURL alloc] init] fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
NSLog(@"New path = %@", [xmlURL absoluteString]);
```

And the output:

```
2010-01-27 15:39:22.105 MusicLibraryStats[28574:a0f] Old path = file://localhost/Users/[username]/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music%20Library.xml
2010-01-27 15:39:22.105 MusicLibraryStats[28574:a0f] New path = (null)
```

First off, the alloc-init shouldn't even be necessary; [other people seem to get away with it](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=428903). In this case, if I don't alloc-init, I get an 'unrecognized selector' error on that line. Of course, now I'm just getting plain old (null).

Where did I goof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `[[NSURL alloc] init]` is not just unnecessary, it's **invalid**. `fileURLWithPath:` is a class method, which means you can only call it on the class object (that is, `NSURL` itself). It does not produce a compile error because `-(NSURL *)init` returns an object of type `id`, and does not result in a runtime error because `-(NSURL *)init` actually returns `nil`, and messages sent to `nil` will just cascade another `nil` as their return value.

<strike>This code should work:</strike>

```
NSString* pathToFile = @"/this/is/a/path";
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
```

**I found your problem.**
`-[NSOpenPanel URLs]` returns an array of NSURL objects, which you treat as NSString objects. That's not right. You should use the following:

```
NSURL* url = [[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

The debugger could've show you that if you looked at the `pathToFile` variable. Make sure to check it next time. :) Hovering a variable with your mouse should get you its type.

However, remember that there are situations where you will legitimately encounter another type than the one you expected. For instance, the private NSPathStore2 class is part of the NSString cluster, and you can do everything NSString supports on NSPathStore2 objects. (If this happens and you're not too sure, check the documentation to see if the type you expect is a cluster type. That's how they're called in the documentation.)

Comment: I see. Thanks. What method is available (if any) to turn the string I have now into what you have?

Breakpoints are indeed useful, but there's not much that I can do with them in this situation. I can step into fileURLWithPath: , but if a runtime error is involved (like when I didn't alloc-init), the best I can do is examine the assembly.

Comment: All you need to do this this: `NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];` If you still have problems, the issue might be with `pathToFile`. Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: Nope, the string is most definitely plain ol' file://localhost/Users/[username]/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music%20Library.xml . It was generated using NSOpenPanel...pathToFile = [[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: You need to invoke the "path" method on the NSUrl to get a file path without the file protocol at the front.